# Restoring packages failing with .NET Core 3.0 and Blazor 3.0 preview 9

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I am trying to restore a package which should be compatible with the latest Blazor and Core .NET 3.0 but Restoring packages keep failing with the error log in the screenshot above.
I have installed additionally .NET frameworks 4.6 to 4.8. I go .NET standard from 1.0 to 2.1, but none of them seems to change the error.

- What is the cause of this error and how to fix it ?

Comment: Is there a reason you've not switched to using the released version?

Comment: I believe it's in the latest.. or it isnt ?

Comment: Final version was released on Monday, no need for previews any more.

Comment: You also missed the release candidate that was released last week.

Comment: There is a newer version but for client-side it is still a Preview. Update though, nobody wants to solve a preview9 problem anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a client side issue. Completely removing the .NET, restart and reinstalling it fix the issue.